Why can't setTimeout be extended even when referring to the timeout ID?
I have multiple commands in discord.js v14 that give the user the same role for different amounts of time (temporary role). /pug30 is for 30 minutes and /pug1 is for 1 hour for example. Why is it that I can reduce the length of time if I use /pug1 and then /pug30 right after, but can't extend it if I use /pug30 and then /pug1? How do I get the timer to extend?
Also, the log always prints "user does not have role" no matter what so for some reason (maybe because each command is a separate interaction?), my code only executes the "if" part of the if statement.
const { CommandInteraction, SlashCommandBuilder, EmbedBuilder } = require('discord.js');


// Object to store timeouts for each user
var userTimeouts = {};


module.exports = {
    data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
        .setName("pug1")
        .setDescription("Adds the user to the PUG Queue for 1 hour."),
          async execute(interaction) {
            const user = interaction.user;
            const role = interaction.guild.roles.cache.find(r => r.name == 'PUG Queue');
            //const role = interaction.guild.roles.cache.get("628292255785943062");
            const member = await interaction.guild.members.fetch(user);

            if (!member.roles.cache.has(role)) {
              console.log('user does not have role')
              member.roles.add(role);

            // Clear previous timeout, if any
              clearTimeout(userTimeouts[user]);
              userTimeouts[user] = null;

            // Set new timeout and store it in userTimeouts
              userTimeouts[user] = setTimeout(() => {
                  member.roles.remove(role);
                  delete userTimeouts[user]; // Cleanup timeout reference
              }, 3600000);

              const embed = new EmbedBuilder()
                  .setTitle(" ")
                  .setDescription(`Added ${interaction.user} to the PUG Queue for 1 hour.`)
                  .setColor(0x4169E1);

              await interaction.reply({ embeds: [embed], ephemeral: false });

            } else {
                console.log('user has the role')
                // Clear previous timeout
                clearTimeout(userTimeouts[user]);
                userTimeouts[user] = null;

                // Set new timeout
                userTimeouts[user] = setTimeout(() => {
                    member.roles.remove(role);
                    delete userTimeouts[user]; // Cleanup timeout reference
                }, 3600000);

                const embed = new EmbedBuilder()
                    .setTitle(" ")
                    .setDescription(`Added ${interaction.user} to the PUG Queue for 1 hour.`)
                    .setColor(0x4169E1);
                    
                await interaction.reply({ embeds: [embed], ephemeral: false });
            }
    }
}



Looking at code for pug1 alone it looks correct to me. Can you also share the code for your pug30? Is it because you forgot to run the clearTimeout(userTimeouts[user]); in pug30 scenario?

isn't it likely that every time this runs it is a new instance? I would guess that any vars outside of the interaction object cannot be relied upon.

@angyc the commands are literally copy and pasted, just changed the times in ms.

@Geoduck I think this is why but I'm not sure how to fix it. Why isn't userTimeouts global?

You are using interaction.user, which is an object, as a key for your userTimeouts mapping. Using object as key will result in the key become the string "[Object object]", hence you get only one single entry in the userTimeouts map, which get overwritten everytime even by different users. Use user.id as the key instead

@RickyMo Thank you! Switched it earlier, but wasn't sure which was correct. That fixed the issue and I can now extend and reduce. Now, I would like to make the if/else statement work. Regardless of whether the user has the role, the bot only executes the if part of the statement. How do I make something like userTimeouts.includes(user)?
